# why does mv not work if the destination directory is too large

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems, mv

I was at work and debugging an automated program that moves x number of files into a directory.

After freezing when listing the directory, I moved it out of the way because it seemed to have too many files (~75000 files | 297MB). At this point I also noticed that when I did "ps ax | grep mv" that a lot of other processes that used move were stuck (even though they were not moving to the same directory).

After moving the directory out of the way and recreating an empty directory it seemed to work and the programs continued to write to the newly created directory but I am curious to know why? Is it because of the limitation of the file system in linux or does it have to do with the way the move command works?

Comment: If you hit a filesystem limit, the syscall will fail outright, it won't hang.

Comment: 75000 files in a directory is probably not a problem in and of itself. What *is* a problem is attempting to creating a command line like `mv * somewhere/else/`, where `*` will expand to those 75000 files and likely cause a "command line too long" error.

Comment: Anyhow, this isn't a bash or shell question in any way or shape whatsoever.

Comment: (Listing a huge directory with `ls` default options is also going to take a lot of time because `ls` does silly things like sorting its results [unless this is turned off with `-f`] rather than just streaming contents directly from the `readdir` syscall. `ls` isn't the only tool to be silly about that either -- I once wrote a Python `ctypes` wrapper around `readdir` because its default directory-listing mechanisms weren't capable of streaming).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you'd used `strace` to watch what `ls` was doing, and validated that the syscall wasn't returning, you'd be in a better place to have a well-supported assertion that there was actually a kernel-level problem here.

Comment: And if you're going to be asking questions about filesystems, you need to **at the very minimum** describe the specific filesystem in use (and any layers on top, such as NFS) for your question to be complete enough to be answerable.

Comment: ...moreover, if the filesystem is ext4, we need to know which options it was formatted with, for instance, whether `dir_index` is enabled. (That doesn't help with `ls`, but it's very relevant to lookup performance when you know the name of a file inside a huge directory and want to get its inode as quickly as possible).

Comment: Finally, it would help seeing the program (script) which you use for moving the files.

Comment: This is the script used to move the files

(shopt -s nullglob; cd %s; for p in %s; do %s $p >>%s; echo \"\" >>%s ; mv $p %s; done) > /dev/null 2>&1

I'm not sure what the file system is but I could find out. I'm just not sure how to do that